# Запрос из БД по расписанию

Tags: postgresql

)

Пока не смогла нужное найти для себя. Задача такая. Периодически таблица в БД будет наполняться данными. Необходимо делать запрос к данным раз в час чтобы получать отчетность. Используется Postgresql. Возможно ли написать запрос, который позволял бы запускать, например триггерную функцию, по расписанию раз в час? Подскажите, пожалуйста, может какой-то толковый источник, если есть желательно бы с примером чтобы могла разобрать и понять.

Или все это делается с помощью какой-то системы/планировщика задач, а запросом не решить это вопрос?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/postgrespro/blog/335798/

Comment: *Возможно ли написать запрос, который позволял бы запускать, например триггерную функцию, по расписанию раз в час?* Абсолютно невозможно. Триггер - это реакция на **изменение** данных.